# Concurrency Issue with ConcurrentLinkedQueue with multiple threads writing and multiple threads reading. #Fast directory scan

Tags: java, multithreading

I have multiple threads writing and reading from the same queue. I am using ConcurrentLinkedQueue. Any thread can add an elements to the queue and any other thread can poll for an element and process it. My problem is if queue is empty I want to the thread that is polling on queue to wait until some element is added to it by some other thread and the whole process should exit if all threads are waiting that is no thread is writing anymore. 
I am using this to list all files in a directory and its subdirectories #faster scan.

Following is code snippet 1:

{

private Queue dList = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue();

/* some processing code */

```
public void Run
{
/* some processing code */
while(dName == null)
{
try{
synchronized(dList){
dList.wait();
}
} catch(InterruptedException e){}
dName = dList.poll();
}

/* some processing code */
{
dList.add(item);
synchronized(dList){
dList.notifyAll();
}
}
}
```

Is above code right? Does it do what I want all the time.  Though program is running fine, I do not understand how threads are exiting as I have not mentioned any exit condition.

Is it right to use synchronized on ConcurrentLinkedQueue?
Does this work with huge directories as well?
EDIT1:
Using LinkedBlockingQueue, but how to exit when all the threads are in waiting state that means no more directories to scan?
Will it work having one static variable, increment it and check it is equal to numberofthreads, then exit. Does it work or are there any better solutions?

EDIT 2:
Thank you all.
Exiting from threads is solved by AtomicInteger. If all threads are waiting on queue, then their AtomicInteger is incremented, if AtomicInteger is equal to number of threads then break;

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is blocking. You are far better off using a datastructure that specifically does that like `ArrayBlockingQueue` rather than roll up one of your own. It does concurrency, but also has blocking ways to access the queue that force the running thread to wait until there's an item to get. With all the required locking etc. You can also do unbounded things with `LinkedBlockingQueue`

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html

This makes it so that you can have consumer threads and producer threads and you don't have to do any of the locking or syncronizing yourself. You just use take() or do a put(item) and the thread will wait if there's not room to put that item or if there's no item to take. It does the relevant locking and unlocking for you. And only waits when it can't really get the item or put it there. There's also operations that will timeout etc.

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) return;
                try {
                    File file = blockingqueue.take();
                } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
                    return;
                }
                processFile(file);
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

---

You don't really have to synchronize the ConcurrentLinkedQueue, it's thread safe. What you're doing is implementing blocking. There are a lot of things to explain how this should be done. It doesn't matter what object you wait and notify on (though must be the same object), the same rules apply.

- You need to wait() in one thread and notify() in another (I can't
  tell if this is the case in your code).
- You need to do so in synchronized blocks synched on the same object. (correct)
- But, you didn't seem to implement any of the other requirements. You need to check whether the queue is empty before you wait, there's no point in waiting just every time for no reason.

Comment: Then I'd have to synchronized it while adding and polling. Is it not costly operation as I have to traverse huge directories?

Comment: With the blocked operation take and put() they would forceably stop the thread until there's either room to put the item or an item to take. But, all the syncronizing is done for you. No need to rebuild the wheel.

Comment: It's a bounded buffer and I do not know how many files are going to be in directories.

Comment: Then use an unbounded version of the datastructure. So LinkedBlockingQueue<>

Comment: So you'd have a thread set to take() the file and process it, and just loop it. And then anything that is fed into the linked blocking queue will be dealt with appropriately. It doesn't need to check if there is a file to take, just try to take() it, it'll wait until there is something to take and then grab it correctly. For any number of threads.

Comment: Thanks, It works. Can you tell me using synchronized on ConcurrentLinkedqueue is right?

Comment: You don't really have to synchronize the ConcurrentLinkedQueue what you are doing is just trying to implement your own blocking. It doesn't matter what object you wait and notify on, the same rules apply. You need to wait() in one thread and notify() in another and you need to do so in synchronized blocks synched on the same object.

Comment: As for your original question, about your code there. I can't tell but it looks like it's in the same code block. You don't wait and notify in the same thread but different threads. You have a consumer thread and a producer thread. And you only pause the consumer with the wait when there's nothing to consume. You seem to be doing something really weird there.

Comment: It's a really fine grained bit of concurrency there. But, generally no. Your code suffers from a series of problems. And at a minimum you need two threads, and only to wait on an empty queue. Syncronize both the wait and notify on the same object. Have one make the data and then call notify and the other be ready to grab items and wait if there's nothing to take. Rarely would you need to implement this yourself, you're much better off with the blocking queue because they are highly efficient (they use atomics etc) and make sure you don't sync or wait more than you have to.

Comment: wait() and notifyall() is in same method but one thread can not be in both wait() and notiall() state anyway. notifyAll ()  is for other threads in wait().  Can you tell me how will while(true) code break.. without passing time limit blockingqueue.take() would be in infinite state, right?

Comment: I am doing all checks, if queue is empty or not, only then goes to wait.. sorry, I have not posted whole code.

Comment: There are other problems like your seeming confusion that interrupting the thread is not notifying it. That catch that calls pull is really weird. And while they cannot be in both wait and notify they can all be in wait and all wait forever with nothing to notify them.

Comment: Infinite waiting is a bit different than infinite looping. Given that it's a producer or consumer thread, it will simply wait forever in either case whether because the queue is full or the queue is empty. You kill the thread by interrupting it when you're done with having a producer. It checks if the thread is interrupted and exits.